# cURL 'server certificate status verification SKIPPED'

Tags: curl, certificate, x509, verification

There's one message regarding certificate verification which I don't quite understand. Here's the command:

curl -v https://www.pearsonhighered.com/mediaproducts/theastudyguide/index.html

And the output:

*Connected to www.pearsonhighered.com (104.68.125.15) port 443 (#0)

- found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
- found 592 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- server certificate verification OK
- server certificate status verification SKIPPED
- common name: www.pearsoned.com (matched)
- server certificate expiration date OK
- server certificate activation date OK
- certificate public key: RSA
- certificate version: #3
- subject: C=GB,postalCode=WC2R 0RL,ST=London,L=London,street=80 Strand,O=Pearson PLC,OU=Hosted by Pearson\, Inc.,OU=Multi-Domain SSL,CN=www.pearsoned.com
- start date: Mon, 12 Mar 2018 00:00:00 GMT
- expire date: Thu, 16 Jan 2020 23:59:59 GMT
- issuer: C=GB,ST=Greater Manchester,L=Salford,O=COMODO CA Limited,CN=COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
- compression: NULL

What does the message 'server certificate status verification SKIPPED' mean?

Answer (score 1):

OCSP verification is skipped if you simply read the source code,

https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/9bdadbbdee61c1726c2f5ee9452fd4cd6a933128/lib/vtls/gtls.c#L1125

Comment: @DAB you can have your opinion, but to this question the code itself is obviously also the answer. If you insist, write a better answer yourself to compete.

Answer (score 0):

As per the curl man page

```
--cert-status

(TLS) Tells curl to verify the status of the server certificate by using the Certificate Status Request (aka. OCSP stapling) TLS extension.

If this option is enabled and the server sends an invalid (e.g. expired) response, if the response suggests that the server certificate has been revoked, or no response at all is received, the verification fails.

This is currently only implemented in the OpenSSL, GnuTLS and NSS backends.

Providing --cert-status multiple times has no extra effect. Disable it again with --no-cert-status.
```

> server certificate status verification SKIPPED

denotes that cert-status is disabled. You can enable it by passing **--cert-status** option

If you are using libcurl then check [this](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS.html)

If the verification fails after enabling, check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/validating-certificates-curl#3-validating-certificates-with-cert-status)